# Jump in Kendo grid template

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have this template in my Kendo grid:

```
{
    title: "operation",
    width: 400,
    lockable: false,
    template: "
        <a title=edit class=\"primary-color knd-custom-action-btn\" href=\"\\#/restaurants/edit/${restaurantId}\" >BrunchCode</a>
        <a class=\"primary-color knd-custom-action-btn\" href=\"\\#/restaurants/edit/${restaurantId}\" ><i class=\"fa fa-pencil\"></i></a>
    "
}
```

This is result of my code :

[image]

When I *click/right click* on font awesome icon , it jumps for first time then I go to destination link , However whenever I *click/right click* on BrunchCode , it works as charm. I have no idea about problem font awesome or Kendo has. Any suggestion?

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue [here](http://dojo.telerik.com/ISEDO)? Is there any additional library/framework you're using to handle those hash urls ?